# How can I reposition offset addresses quickly?

Tags: javascript, c++, python, pointers, hex

I have a file with information.
Each section of information is located at a certain offset. There are about 100 sections of information. Every section of information starts at the beginning of the word "LPS"
At the beginning of the file there is a **list** of offset addresses that point to each section of information.

For example:

"**801F 0B00**" link to the offset "**B1F80**" where a new section of information starts
"**80B0 0B00**" refers to the offset "**BB080**" where a new section of information starts

I'm adding/shortening the information of those lines, so I need to change the offsets at the beginning of the file (the list) to make them coincide with the new locations.

So, what code exactly would help me to do this automatically?
For example, the tool must recognize the offset addresses (the list)
Allow me to add the new information
Then, modify the list of offset with the new locations.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "pointer addresses"? Neither Javascript nor Python works with pointers directly, and any pointers you write to a file are going to be invalidated when your program exits. And how are you going to fit enough information to usefully point anywhere into only 4 bits?

Comment: I mean this: at the beginning of the file there's a list of pointers such as "0436 0B00" which refer to offset "B3604", a word "LPS" starts at that location with some information. With the new information I'm adding I have to relink the pointers to the new offsets. How do I do that?

Comment: Normally those would be called "offsets"

Comment: I'm sorry about confusing the terminology. I just need a faster way to changing the offsets to the new locations. Doing this manually takes too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume the file has 100 offsets and strings.
Once you see how it works you change the 100 to be variable.

To read the file, do this

```
#define N 100
typedef int OFFSET;  // assume int is 4 btyes and big enough to hold a file offset
OFFSET offset[ N ];
// offset[N-1] is 1 past the end of the last data string
// read the N offsets from file into offset[]

std::string data[ N ];
for( int i = 0; i < N-1; i++ ) {
    size_t len = offset[i+1] - offset[i] - 1;
    // read 'len' bytes at offset[i] into data[i]
}
```

Now you make changes to the strings in data[] and want to rewrite the file.
To write a new file do this

```
offset[0] = sizeof(offset);   // start of data in the file
for( int i = 1; i < N; i++ ) {
    offset[i] = offset[i-1] + data[i-1].size();
}
// Write the offset[] array to the file

for( int i = 0; i < N-1; i++ ) {
    // write data[i] at offset[i] in the file
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Not sure how to proceed, I'm a complete newbie. I have copied to a compiler but it doesn't work, as it shows lexical error at #

Answer (score 0):

Each offset is a byte-reversed hex pointer to the location. So you need to convert the pointers to integers.

You aren't really clear about what you're asking, but assuming you have a file that has something like:

offset0A
offset0B
offset0C
offset0D
data

You should read all the offsets into an array of integers, each of which is the value of an offset.

Then read the rest of the data into a big block. Remember what the base offset of the data block was.

Then start updating your data. Everytime you insert bytes into the data block, you need to update all the pointers that start after the insertion point by the quantity of bytes you insert.

So if you have:

1000 0000
2000 0000
3000 0000
data

Suppose you insert "sometext" at offset 2400. You can then walk your list of offsets. 1000 < 2400, so you don't touch that one, or the one at 2000. But 3000 >= 2400 so you need to change that offset to 3008.

Continue to do this for all your insertions. When you're done, write out the set of offsets first, then the data.